# Stop `sudo apt-get remove git` from removing Atom text editor automatically

Tags: git, atom-editor

I am removing `git` using `$ sudo apt-get remove git`. But along with it I notice that it writes

```
Removing atom (1.45.0) ...
Removing git (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.7) ...
```

And all of a sudden, Atom gets removed. This is quite annoying. Is this a bug (and should be reported) or am I doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The atom package has `Depends: git` in its metadata. It cannot be installed if the `git` package is not installed. If you think that it should be able to work without git installed, complain to the maintainers of that package.

If you are providing the git command on your system some other way, you might want to look into using `equivs` to create a package which `Provides: git` and `Replaces: git`.